# Do gluon jets occur spontaneously in the real world, or only in a particle accelerator?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

In [this](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/the-known-apparently-elementary-particles/jets-the-manifestation-of-quarks-and-gluons/) article by Matt Strassler, he says "A struck quark, like any accelerated particle, will radiate.  A suddenly accelerated quark will radiate many gluons.  So what actually emerges at the edge of the proton is not a fast quark but a collection of fast gluons along with the fast quark.  The shape of the jet is actually determined mainly by the way that the gluons are radiated before the quark even emerges from the proton."
Is this something that occurs spontaneously in the real world, or only in a particle accelerator?

I find this to be an issue in many science papers, where they do not mention if what they are describing only occurs in a lab.

Comment: As far as I understand, gluon jets mean a separate bunch of gluons propagating, whereas in the nuclear matter, they are tightly bound with the quarks and themselves, where there is no notion of a plane wave.

Comment: My guess would be that many many things occur inside a supernova, including jets of gluons. Whether you consider that the real world or not is another question.

Comment: @JonCuster  I was thinking of the real world as here on Earth, in normal every day situations.  A supernova would not be inside that grouping.  There are lots of particles, like neutrinos, flying around all the time.  Are they enough to cause gluon jetting?

Comment: Well, the most energetic particles we have ever detected are cosmic rays, and one of them could presumably undergo such an interaction while inside the Earth's atmosphere. Detecting it would be a different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extremely high-energy cosmic rays, when they strike the Earth's atmosphere, spontaneously cause many of the reactions that we normally see only in particle accelerators, and in particularly high-energy cases it would not at all be surprising to see a gluon jet. In fact, their energy is often *orders of magnitude higher* than we can produce in particle accelerators. The highest-energy cosmic ray possessed something like 320 EeV, or equivalently 320 million TeV, of energy, while the LHC produces collisions with a center-of-mass energy of a measly 13 TeV in comparison.

As far as actually *directly observing* a gluon jet from a cosmic-ray interaction in the upper atmosphere, the main problem is that we don't really have too many particle detectors that are just sitting in the upper atmosphere, at a spot where a high-energy cosmic-ray interaction happens to take place. So we inevitably observe these reactions from a significant distance, which means the short-length characteristics of the reaction are often obscured by the resulting particle shower as the products of the reaction hit other particles in the atmosphere, dispersing their energy over a wider and wider cone.

Comment: do cosmic rays not reach the earth surface, and in fact pass right through the earth, so it would be happening everywhere?

Comment: @foolishmuse Depends on what you mean by "cosmic rays". The vast majority of _primary_ cosmic rays, the ones coming from outer space that hit Earth's upper atmosphere, are protons and helium nuclei, and they don't penetrate very far into the atmosphere at all. But the _secondary_ cosmic rays, the products of that initial interaction, can include things like muons and neutrinos, which _do_ penetrate the atmosphere (and kilometers of solid rock, in the case of most muons, or the entire Earth, in the case of most neutrinos).

Comment: So would these neutrinos and muons have sufficient energy to cause gluon jets?  If so, are we speaking of very large numbers, or just a few?

Comment: @foolishmuse Certainly some of them would, in principle, but the probability of actually transferring enough energy to cause something like this (rather than merely having a "glancing collision" where the incident particle keeps most of its energy) is very low. Even moreso for neutrinos, which barely interact with anything to begin with.